# PopViewcontroller and pushViewController not working in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I facing problem while pop and push `viewcontroller`. I have one `viewController` in which i have added images using `ImagePickerViewController`. When i open any image and edit that image save it and pop to `viewController` that working fine but when i pop that controller that's not working.

can anyone help me and suggest what is issue?
Thanks

Comment: Please show code where you facing problem it is not iOS 10 issue

Comment: Correct!!
Share some code as its problem with setup and method calls I guess.

Comment: May be `navigationController` is `nil`?

Comment: NSArray *viewcontrollers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @RonakChaniyara I have checked my viewcontroller array it have 3 objects.

Comment: okay, then update your question with related code so that people can help.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code like below:

```
NSArray *viewcontrollers = self.navigationController.viewControllers; 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```